# Download affy annotation file with python

Tags: python

I want to download an affymetrix annotation file. But it needs to log in first.

The log in page is https://www.affymetrix.com/estore/user/login.jsp
The file I want to download is:
http://www.affymetrix.com/Auth/analysis/downloads/na32/genotyping/GenomeWideSNP_6.na32.annot.db.zip

I have try some method but I cannot figure it out.

#

```
    from requests import session
    payload = {
        'action': 'login',
        'username': 'username',   #This part should be changed
        'password': 'password'    #This part should be changed
    }

    with session() as c:
        c.post('https://www.affymetrix.com/estore/user/login.jsp', data=payload)
        request = c.get('http://www.affymetrix.com/Auth/analysis/downloads/na32/genotyping/GenomeWideSNP_6.na32.annot.db.zip')
        print request.headers
        print request.text
```

#

I also try urllib2,

```
    import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password})
    opener.open('https://www.affymetrix.com/estore/user/login.jsp', login_data)
    resp = opener.open('http://www.affymetrix.com/Auth/analysis/downloads/na32/genotyping/GenomeWideSNP_6.na32.annot.db.zip')
    resp.read()
```

Comment: You'll have to go through the page source to locate the endpoint of the POST (as it's not the URL you're using at the moment) - it looks like the submit button is handled by Javascript, so you've probably got a bit of work...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the URL that the information is getting posted to.

`https://www.affymetrix.com/estore/user/login.jsp?_DARGS=/estore/user/login.jsp`

here is the information that is being posted.

[image: post data]